# print_r(): Property access is not allowed yet

Tags: php, debugging

I have an error reporting class that is called when an error occurs. It is to report the error on browser or email. The class itself results in a Warning message reported.

```
print_r(): Property access is not allowed yet
```

This is the code that generates the Warning:

```
foreach ( func_get_args() as $arg )
    print_r($arg);
```

PHP Version 5.4.37

Here is more detailed code:

```
class MyErrHandler
{
    private static $_currErr='';

    public static function displayError()
    {
        ob_start();

        foreach ( func_get_args() as $arg )
            print_r($arg);

        .....
```

Comment: try this func_get_args — Returns an array comprising a function's argument list  $arg = func_get_args();
    print_r($arg);

Comment: @JYoThI if you meant that I replace my foreach and print_r code to this assignment and print_r code that you provided, I just tried this and it still generates same Warning

Comment: tried few more things.... like `empty($arg)` and `$arg !== null` check before calling print_r on it.... but it does not work

Comment: also tried using var_dump instead of print_r... and the error changes to `var_dump(): Property access is not allowed yet`

Comment: @ImranAhmed this type of error occur when function does not return true value, can you check your func_get_args working properly or not.

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: @Kumar I tried empty() and null check on the fun_get_args() result... but it still causes the same Warning... I also tried a try/catch... but it catches no exception

Comment: @Kumar If you meant that I post defination of func_get_args()... then it is php's native function... its not a user defined function...

Comment: If this function is called from the outermost scope of a file which has been included by calling include or require from within a function in the calling file, it now generates a warning and returns FALSE.

Comment: I just tried by adding a check `$arg != FALSE` and `$arg !== FALSE` before calling print_r($arg)... but that also does not work and throws the warning

Comment: @Kumar is there a way to check the situation that you just mentioned..??

Comment: I am surprise to see that nobody has asked to see which arguments are really being passed to the function. Can you provide a sample code that actually shows what arguments are expected to be passed to MyErrHandler::displayError()?